# MySQL how to make a column of child table point to the parent table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I've just started MySQL database and i am confused with what a foreign key could do.

Suppose i have a parent table (teacher) of this and taxno is the primary key;

```
taxno   Tfname   Tlname   Tgender   Tquali    Thours      

1111    TOH       JIM       M       HONOURS    120
```

and my childtable (teacsub);

```
taxno   Tfname   Tlname   Tgender   Tquali    Thours  Subtitle Subtype
```

How do i make it that if, for example, my input for teacsub is

```
 taxno   Tfname   Tlname   Tgender   Tquali    Thours  Subtitle   Subtype

 1111   dddd       dddd      F       weqwe      100     HISTORY     3
```

it will prompmt to me that my input for teacsub is wrong?

i have created a foreign key for taxno but it only applies to taxno.

Comment: you shouldnt have all the repeated fields from the parent table, in the second. that's what the relation is for. `tfname`, `tlname`, `tgender`, `tquali`, `thours` are all properties of teacher, not the second table.

Comment: does it mean all i need to do for teacsub is to just change the entire table to just taxno, subtitle and subtype?

Comment: yes. and then use a `join` to associate the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of a relational db is that with properly constructed tables, you do not need to repeat information as you have been doing.

If your `teacher` table contains information like a persons name, gender etc, you do not need to duplicate this information anywhere else.

For example, if your `teacsub` table is simply `teacsub(taxno, subtitle, subtype)`, then you can get your 'full' information by joining the two tables together with a query like this:

```
select *
  from teacher
    inner join teacsub
      on teacher.taxno = teacsub.taxno
```

And that will happily go off and pull all rows from both tables that share a common `taxno`